# Strategies for reducing CPU and Reads when creating/updating index is not an option

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is a generalized question as I am looking for a variety of solutions from the community.

I have a stored procedure that on a particular JOIN in a temp table it has CPU that is too high.  This is a relative 'too high' as it is over 200 CPU and our threshold for stored procedures is 800 CPU.  The other JOINs are lower but when added to my 200+ CPU temp table it goes over.

This particular table does have a single nonclustered index outside of the default clustered index.  Even when using the correct conditions the optimizer uses the clustered index.  I can force it to use the nonclustered index but this quadruples the reads (putting me over our read threshold) and only lowers the CPU by a little more than half, so my CPU is better but not great still.

I have already discussed that there is a missing index (according to SQL Sentry) with my DBA but because the columns I need are not heavily used he won't create a new index or include my columns in the current index - this brings me to the point where I disclose that there is a key lookup involved.

I may not have any other solutions and I may have to live with one either the high CPU or high reads, but I wanted to know if there were other options I wasn't aware of and thus the question here, to this great community.

Sample of what the code looks like:

```
SELECT
      qbcl.UniqueID [PropertyHmy],
      CONVERT(DATETIME, qbcl.SomeDate)  [SomeDate],
      x.MonthStart [MonthStart],
      x.MonthEnd [MonthEnd],
      ISNULL(qbcl.SomeInt, 0) [SomeIntCount],
      qbcl.TypeID [TypeID],
      qbcl.FileLogID [FileLogID],
      qbcl.CancelFileLogID [CancelFileLogID],
      qbcl.ApproveFileLogID [ApproveFileLogID],
      qbcl.ReadyAt [ReadyAt],
      qbcl.ExportedAt [ExportedAt]
FROM
      #SomeTempTable x
      JOIN SomeTable qbcl WITH (INDEX(IX_SomeTable_2A_10A)) ON qbcl.UniqueID = x.PropertyHmy 
          AND qbcl.TypeID = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
      qbcl.UniqueID [PropertyHmy],
      CONVERT(DATETIME, qbcl.SomeDate) [SomeDate],
      x.MonthStart [MonthStart],
      x.MonthEnd [MonthEnd],
      ISNULL(qbcl.SomeInt, 0) [SomeIntCount],
      qbcl.TypeID [TypeID],
      NULL [FileLogID],
      NULL [CancelFileLogID],
      NULL [ApproveFileLogID],
      NULL [ReadyAt],
      NULL [ExportedAt]
FROM
      #SomeTempTable x
      JOIN SomeTable qbcl WITH (INDEX(IX_SomeTable_2A_10A)) ON qbcl.UniqueID = x.PropertyHmy 
          AND qbcl.TypeID = 2
```

From my SomeTable example, almost all the columns are not included in the index and cause a key lookup.

[Link to my execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syw1kMTnL).

And a screenshot of the same plan:
[image: ExePlan]

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: How useful to performance is `SomeTable.TypeID`, i.e. do relatively few rows have it set to `1`?

Comment: @HABO I will work on getting an execution plan added shortly - as for your question - the TypeID is useful in that it is the field required, in addition to UniqueID, for the nonclustered index.  It isn't useful.  I have a second JOIN just like this one where TypeID = 2 that grabs the rest of the rows needed and they are combined in a UNION ALL.

Comment: @HABO, I updated the sample code and added Execution Plan as requested